# Comprehension questions

Tags: discussion

The recent question, 
[What does this mean: "The more you fence in Iran, the harder it will be for the rest of the world"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/287/what-does-this-mean-the-more-you-fence-in-iran-the-harder-it-will-be-for-the), seems to be more of a reading comprehension question. This is obviously a skill that is important for an english language learner, but how should they be treated on this site?

I think they should be allowed to a certain extent. For example, I don't want the site to become a place for people to post all their homework questions. But maybe others have different opinions?